# Show that $n(t+1)=(1+r)e^{-\alpha n(t)}n(t)$ is equivalent to $n(t+1)=(1+r)^{1-\frac{n(t)}{K}} n(t)$ where $K=\frac{\ln (1+r)}{\alpha}$

Tags: mathematical-modeling

Show that $n(t+1)=(1+r)e^{-\alpha n(t)}n(t)$ is equivalent to $n(t+1)=(1+r)^{1-\frac{n(t)}{K}} n(t)$ where $K=\frac{\ln (1+r)}{\alpha}$

I also have to show that $n(t+1)$ will grow when $r<0$ and the initial population is greater than $n=k$.
I have also tried to show this but using both variations of the equation I get an increasingly negative value.

Comment: What would happen if you substitute $\alpha = \frac {\ln(1+r)}K$ into the LHS? By the way, please type out the question instead of using images.

Comment: please use mathjax, and show your work, writing about failure doesn't help with solving the problem

Comment: There, cleaned up your post, please instead of spending the time writing a sad story of failure use it to provide information of what has been tried instead. Also please learn mathjax